# Ошибка при чтении HTML-файла

Tags: html, python

Почему не работает, данный код (url не считаем). Вот он:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen('https://drgn.site/double').read()
search_string = '<div class="left bg>'
number_string = html.find(search_string)
html = html[number_string:-1]
```

Вот ошибка:

> ```
> number_string = html.find(search_string)
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
> ```

Comment: Потому что в байтах можно искать только байты, а вы строк пихаете

Answer (score 0):

В тексте ошибки все сказано.
Сделайте так:

```
res = urlopen('https://drgn.site/double').read()
html = res.decode('utf-8')
```